# How to Build 64-bit using Expo CLI React-Native

Tags: react-native, build, 64-bit, expo

Need 64-bit requirements for Google Playstore. I using Expo 33.0.0 and

react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-33.0.0.tar.gz",

Answer (score 1):

[Expo will support 64 bit when SDK 34 is released later this month.](https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/4374#issuecomment-504998837)

Comment: Thank you very much. So now we can only wait until there is a version SDK 34?

Comment: Please check my answer and update Your comment. I don't want to downvote, but is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

64-bit builds can be made with SDK33, as stated in [this github comment](https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/4374#issuecomment-509636802):

> 64-bit support has been released to our builders for **SDK33**, it's there enabled by default. The size of the final APK might be bigger because of this additional architecture, however I recommend to use -t app-bundle when running `expo build:android` - this will give you app bundle instead of APK, which contains binaries for each architecture separately so your users after all *will be downloading less* from the store

What I am not sure about is the version of `expo-cli` needed for the build. I can't find that information anywhere.. On the [expo.io blog](https://blog.expo.io/64-bit-support-and-android-app-bundles-fe0c6a28669), they suggest having the latest `expo-cli`, but they don't say anything about the version.

I hope they will have more info on this soon, since it is already 24th of July.